# ASP.net: How to Test a LINQ Query

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

How can I test a LINQ Query such as the following:

```
var vUser = (from u in this.dbName.aspnet_Users
                         where u.UserName.Equals(this.wCreateUser.UserName)
                         select u).Single();
```

I keep getting a null exception for vUser, however I am positive such a user exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The record would have to exist or the exception would have to be thrown during evaluation of the lambda, otherwise the exception thrown would be to the effect of

> The sequence contains no elements.

Are you accessing any properties on the `vUser` object after the query or is the `this.wCreateUser` object possibly null?

**Edit**: for comments..

If the exception is that the sequence contains no elements, the query being generated is not returning a result. I would recommend you examine the query being generated and test it directly against the SQL Server..

You can do this a few ways.

1. Open SQL Profiler and watch the
   query being executed.
2. Attach a TextWriter to the DataContext.Log so you can see the
   output of the query (example
   below)..
3. Use LINQPad as the other answer suggested.

.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
this.dcLAUNCHOnline.Log = writer;
//Execute Query..
//sb.ToString(); //will contain the sql produced by the LINQ Query
```

Comment: I do get the "The sequence contains no elements." error.

this.wCreateUser is not null - I have a watch variable on it in visual studio :(

Comment: Good deal! That's a solution I commonly use to log and reproduce queries.

Answer (score 4):

Use SQL profiler and see what SQL is fired by your code. You can try [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) too to run linq query against a DB.